# Gaussian elimination - pivoting using slicing in python

Tags: python, numpy, pivot, slice

I'm trying to implement pivoting for the Gaussian elimination in Python and face some problems.

```
def pivot2(matrix,i):
    # matrix is a N*N matrix
    # i is the column I want to start with

    m = matrix.shape[1]
    for n in range(i,m):
        colMax = np.argmax(abs(matrix[n:,i]), axis=0) #rowindex of highest absolute value in column
        if(colMax == 0): #if max in column is in first row, stop
            break;
        tmpRow = copy.copy(matrix[n,:]) #create new object of same row
        matrix[n,:] = matrix[colMax,:]  #overwrite first row with row of max value
        matrix[colMax,:] = tmpRow       #overwrite old row of max value
    return matrix
```

The code works for `i=0` just fine. However for `i=1` I can't search for the index of the maximum value in the whole column because it will obviously always be `0`.

When I slice this matrix from a 3x3 matrix:

```
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [-3., -2.]])
```

and use my `argmax` function, the index is `1`. But in my original matrix the index of the same row is 2 and it swaps the wrong rows. How do I fix this?

And is there a simpler way to implement pivoting using slices?

Comment: looks like you can just add `i` to `colmax` after checking for 0 and it 'll work fine

Answer (score 2):

You just have to add `i` to `colmax` after checking for 0:

```
...
if(colMax == 0): #if max in column is in first row, stop
    break;
colmax += i   # add this string    
...
```